# What does the Bible verse saying "don't boil a goat in its mother's milk" mean?

Tags: eastern-orthodox

Does it mean don't use the word of God (milk meat and honey) condemning the little ones just learning the word of Christ to the point. The child rejects even hearing about God?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do not boil a goat in its mothers milk](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14477/do-not-boil-a-goat-in-its-mothers-milk)

Comment: Though it may be a possible duplicate (those claims are often quite subjective), this is an interpretive question. It is one of the Levitical ‘hedges of the law’; forbidding cruelty. This is not a comment answer. But I would provoke the question ‘who says?’; who am I that’s answered your question? You must at least show that you have your own thoughts about this. Scalpers will come along and tear this question apart, for not.  Read the christianity.se site tour; consider helpful comments. This question will need some help. Blessings.

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/15/11555   This may assist you in your search

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14379/12082   And there is this on the Judaism site

Comment: “Teachings about God are difficult to understand. Don’t accept new spiritual teachings about God that look too good, and too easy, to be true; they have probably been deliberately ‘cooked up’ to deceive you”.      There is a line of reasoning that delves the metaphoric interpretation of the command. If this gets reopened I may answer but I'm not sure if it is a Eastern Orthodox view.

Answer (score 1):

One of several Jewish interpretations of this verse may be found here: http://thetorah.com/meat-and-milk-origins-in-the-text/

The one that appeals to me is that it was misinterpreted and originally meant that you should not wait until a young goat has been weaned before bringing it for sacrifice of first fruits.

Another idea with no evidential support is that it is forbidding a pagan practice common at that time.

Answer (score -1):

It means that we should avoid, or minimizing, eating milk that has continuously been boiled, because when it is being boiled for a long time, which it is when meat is being cooked in it, it becomes concentrated due to water evaporation.

Milk contains a relatively big percentage of saturated fat, which is unhealthy to drink/eat too much of. Skim milk, and small quantities of semi skimmed milk is a lot healthier than creamy full-fat milk, etc.

The Bible warns against eating animal fat.

> Lev 7:23 (NIV) “Say to the Israelites: ‘Do not eat any of the fat of cattle, sheep or goats"

Comment: So it is a health issue? I don't think that is why the practice was forbidden

Comment: @Kris I followed one of your links and read this: "As for the prohibition against eating meat [boiled] in milk, it is in my opinion not improbable that — in addition to this being undoubtedly very gross food and very filling — idolatry had something to do with it. Perhaps such food was eaten at one of the ceremonies of their cult or at one of their festivals". However, since the Israelites were not involved in idolatry, it would still not be wise to eat food prepared like this, due to " this being undoubtedly very gross food and very filling".

Comment: Perhaps being the keyword. But who knows other parts of the law were given to protect the health of the Israelites.

Comment: @Kris The reference is this one, by the way: "Jacob Milgrom considers four theories about how the command came about"; in Jon Ericson's post/Hermeneutics.

Comment: -1 No evidence anyone thinks this, and no religious connection.

Comment: @Disciple. There is a scriptural support in Cain and Abel's sacrifices.

Comment: @Constantthin I'd like to hear that evidence; maybe better in chat than here? Cain apparently sacrificed neither milk nor meat, and I didn't see any clue whether milk was or was not involved in Abel's sacrifice.

Comment: @Disciple. The answer is that 'it boils down to' saturated fat concentration, and potential capillary clogging

Comment: Illnesses can be cured by prayer and by 'walking on water'. "Life is in the blood", and tissue death occurs if blood flow is blocked. The greek word 'sozo', that is found in the bible, means to be saved AND HEALED. The verse in Leviticus is hyperbole, warning us of non-moderation in consumption of foods containing saturated fat, which especially some foods derived from animals contain. The bad cholesterol LDL derives from saturated fat.